# ViewBinding manipulate view after inflating

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I have an instance where I used to pass my `View` onto a new method to manipulate a couple of things. here I will provide an example. So Basically I am using a `RecyclerView` and I am `inflating` the view when the `recylerview` creates the `view`

So now I have the inflated `View` object now I just pass it to my method to manipulate it.

`manipulateView(view)` `manipulateView` sets up the color and attributes for the `view children`

and that used to work and everything. but now I am moving onto `ViewBinding`

now I have a `ViewStub` for where I need to `inflate` my `customView`

as follows here is the code

```
ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, getLayoutResource(), viewGroup, false);
ViewStub viewStub = (ViewStub) viewDataBinding.getRoot().findViewById(R.id.stub);
```

and then I set the layout for the `viewStub` here

```
viewStub.setLayoutResource(getLayoutResource());
```

now `setLayoutResource` expects an `int` value with the `id` of the `layout` now my question is how can I call `manipulateView` on `getLayoutResource()` should I just pass the `viewStub` and then call `viewStub.getRootView()` and `Manipulate` that view?

It would be the best if I was able to `manipulate` the `ViewDataBinding` object it self, Should I just manipulate `ViewDataBinding::getRoot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view that gets inflated by calling `layoutInflater.inflate(...)` is the same view you would get from `viewDataBinding.getRoot()`. From the docs, root ["returns the outermost view"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#getroot).

So, if that's what you want to manipulate, I would just call `manipulateView(viewDataBinding.root)`.

Comment: and that will show changes onto the view? like it's the same view and doesn't create a new view object?

Comment: Correct. `View myView = layoutInflater.inflate(...)` and `View myView = binding.getRoot()` return the same thing. :) So that line is all you have to change, the rest of your code should be similar.

Comment: Also, worth noting that in databinding you don't need `findViewById`, you should be able to do `binding.myViewId` and get a reference to the view. That's one of the beauties of databinding. More on that here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/no-more-findviewbyid-457457644885

Comment: I see, my views don't actually have id's they have tags, so should I just do `view::findViewByTag`?

Comment: Hmm thats weird i can't seem to do `binding.hello.setText`, say's "hello" is unresolved ofc I replaced `hello` with my `id`

Comment: How ever, This answer is correct so I have marked it as correct :)

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to bring this up further in the Android chat sometime and if I'm online I can help. If it's a project on GitHub even better, I can take a look.